# How to add a customHeaderLeft button on a screen with goBack functionality using react-navigation in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="MyProfile"
      component={Profile}
      options={{
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        title: 'My Profile',
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <DrawerIcon size={30} color={'white'} name="md-reorder-two-sharp" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeft: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-back-sharp"
              size={22}
              color="white"
              style={{ marginRight: 7, marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 3 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  <ModalPortal />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Below is the code I used for my stack navigation, and I want to go back from that screen

```
1.headerLeft: () => <TouchableOpacity>
  <Ionicons name="arrow-back-sharp" size={22} color="white" style={{ marginRight: 7, marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 3 }} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve this

#### **1.) Set `options` On the Screen itself**

You can use the `useLayoutEffect` hook to achieve this

On the screen where you want to put this header, i.e., the `Profile` screen just add the following code

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerLeft: () => (
      <Ionicons
        name="arrow-back-sharp"
        size={22}
        color="white"
        style={{ marginRight: 7, marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 3 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        // make sure you destructure the navigation variable from the props
        // or otherwise you'll have to write it like this
        // onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}
      />
    ),
  });
}, [navigation]);
```

And your Navigation Container should look like

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="MyProfile"
      component={Profile}
      options={{
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        title: 'My Profile',
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerShadowVisible: false,
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  <ModalPortal />
</NavigationContainer>;
```

Have a look at the [Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/custom-header-component-react-navigation) Here

#### **2.) Set the `headerLeft` and `headerRight` props in the Navigation Container**

Setting the properties in the NavigationContainer, like this

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{}}>
    <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="MyProfile"
      component={Profile}
      options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        title: 'My Profile',
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <DrawerIcon size={30} color={'white'} name="md-reorder-two-sharp" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeft: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Ionicons
              name="arrow-back-sharp"
              size={22}
              color="white"
              style={{ marginRight: 7, marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 3 }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      })}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  <ModalPortal />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Have a look at the [Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/rn-6-custom-header-buttons) Here

Comment: const navigation = useNavigation();   onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}  shows error Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?

Comment: it is possible in navigation 5 buthow to do it with navigation 6?

Comment: thanks bro first way is true because if i use second way then other property are not works

Comment: @RutvikPrajapati Yes, both the ways are possible using `React Navigation 6`. Just make sure your syntax is correct or have a look at the Snack that I've added into the answers for both the ways

Answer (score 1):

You have provided a `TouchableOpacity` as the back button but you haven't specified any `onPress` callback. You should provide an `onPress` callback to your `TouchableOpacity`.

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{}}>
    <Stack.Screen name='home' component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen 
      name='MyProfile'
      component={Profile} 
      options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        title: 'My Profile',
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <DrawerIcon size={30} color={'white'} name='md-reorder-two-sharp' />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerLeft: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.goBack()}>
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back-sharp" size={22} color="white" style={{ marginRight: 7, marginTop: 1, marginLeft: 3 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      })} 
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  <ModalPortal />
</NavigationContainer>
```

If you just wanted to change the back button appearance only, You are better off with `headerBackImage` props of `react-navigation` stack.

Here's a [Live Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/navigation-custom-backbutton)

Comment: this thing will work but i also want to appyle those other props of  headerTransparent: true, these props arenot apply if i use this technique, what should i do?

Comment: what do you mean the other properties are not working?

Comment: i used headerTransparent: true it will shows background image which i used as a background image instead of it default white color and headertint color is by default black i used white color for tint. so these properties are not works if i use this approach so i use navigation option inside useLayoutEffect on profile screen and set implement header there as above mention code answered by @kartikey you can check in by cloning my repo https://github.com/rutvikER1999/RN_Project2.git

Comment: your answer is right but i want my header transparent that is why

Comment: @RutvikPrajapati This should work with other props too.. If you take a look at the snack and navigate to Profile screen. You can see that the profile screen has transparent header.